# Parse XML and change data according to a priority list

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to read and modify XML data on the fly using a priority list with Java. As the XML data is processed, the program should match the current node with the priority list and decide based on this list what action to execute for the node. The list would look something like this:

```
/root/child[1]/data1;   action1
/root/child/data1;      action2
/root/child/*;          action3
//*;                    generic action
```

for a XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <child>
        <data1>child 1 data1 value</data1>
        <data2>child 1 data2 value</data2>
    </child>
    <child>
        <data1>child 2 data1 value</data1>
        <data2>child 2 data2 value</data2>
    </child>
</root>
```

The problem I have with this concept is that I can't "reverse" the XPath logic (XPath selects nodes, I need to match already selected nodes). Is there any convenient way of doing this?

Comment: XSLT allows you to write template and give them priorities, e.g. `<xsl:template match="/root/child[1]/data" priority="10">...</xsl:template>` so perhaps XSLT is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thought about using XSLT, too. Concerns are that xslt can get really messy and unreadable really fast, but I will look into this again. XSLT only applies only one template based on the priority, right?

Comment: XSLT 2.0 available for Java with Saxon 9 has `<xsl:next-match/>` which would allow you to apply the next matching template with lower priority.